# python idle editor no autocomplete list from import/as

Tags: python, windows, import, autocomplete, python-idle

## Problem:

When I add `import winreg as wr` at the start, the autocomplete works for winreg. but not for wr.

### What I tried

- Waiting 2 seconds or pressing Control+Space to trigger the autocomplete box after the dot
- Uninstalled(python 2.7 and 3.4) and reinstalled(pyton 3.4) because my first python was 2.7 and I changed a bunch of reg entries to switch from 2.7 to 3.4
- On the shell window autocomplete for winreg works without even importing it, after I imported it as wr, autocomplete for wr. worked, but why it wont work it the IDLE editor?
- Created a new .py file and tested the import/as
- Tried it on my win 7 and win 8 PC, same problem

### Versions

- Python 3.4
- IDLE 3.4
- Win 7/8

### Sample

```
import winreg as wr

#IDLE behavior: bad
winreg. #autocomplete box is shown
wr. #no autocomplete box

#Runtime behavior: good
print(wr.REG_LINK) #no error, prints 6
print(winreg.REG_LINK) #raises exception, which is good
```

Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong, can I fix it?

Can you recommend another python IDE(lightweight) or a better autocomplete plugin for notepad++?

If you need any other information please tell me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the contents of namespace in which the name to be completed is evaluated. It is currently a combination of contents of sys.modules and globals in the user process if there is one, else the Idle process. See this CPython [tracker issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue18766) for more.  Also see Completions under Tips in help / Idle help.  I am not sure exactly what you did, but here is what I get, which corresponds to the doc.

With installed 3.4.1 on win7, in the Shell.

```
>>> winreg.
```

This works because Idle on Windows imports winreg.  It in in sys.modules even though it is otherwise not in globals.  I think this is partly a bug, but I understand that sys.modules is used as a partial workaround in lieu of a better solution.

```
>>> wr.
```

Does not work, because 'wr' is not in sys.modules (and never will be) and neither in globals().

```
>>> import winreg as wr
```

In interactive mode, this is executed immediately and adds 'wr' to globals.

```
>>> wr.
```

Now works because 'wr' now *is* in globals.

Now, in a file:

```
import winreg as wr
```

This is not executed immediately.

```
wingreg.
```

Works for me, for the same reason as before, So I do not understand your report.

```
wr.
```

Does not work for me, for the same reason as before.  Now remove the two lines and run the file. Now wr. does work, because running the file adds 'wr' to globals.  But running another file would reset globals and 'wr' would likely not be included or might point to the wrong object.  So, no implementation bug that I can reproduce, but a design I hope to improve.